# How to pass variables into graphql-tag from node.js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have the following function:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
global.fetch = fetch

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'myUri'
  })
const getPostsByCategory = async category => {
    const res = await client.query({
        query: gql`
          query articlesByCategory($id: String!) {
            postsByCategory(id: $id) {
              id
            }
          }
        `
      })
      console.log('res', res)
}
```

I want to invoke the function as:

```
await getPostsByCategory('news')
```

however I just can't understand how I pass the category variable into the query. I want to use `qraphql-tag` in my queries and not pass a simple tagged literal as the query.

Comment: if you try to replace $id with category          postsByCategory(id: ${category})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `variables` key in your `client.query` function params as the following

```js
const getPostsByCategory = async category => {
  const res = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query articlesByCategory($id: String!) {
        postsByCategory(id: $id) {
          id
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
        id: category,
    },
  });
  console.log('res', res);
};
```